# Does Xur's engram decode the same for each character that I purchase it with in a given weekend?

Tags: ps4, destiny

Xur has an engram for sale this weekend.  I bought it with my hunter and it was a hunter helm.  If I buy it with my Titan, will it be the same hunter helm, or is the engram different each decode?
Given a visit to Xur in the same weekend and enough motes of light to purchase the engram from Xur.
I understand I am not gauranteed to receive armor for the character that I bought it with (e.g. I could have received a titan helm).

Comment: I bought 5 of these when the expansion came out. He was selling head engrams. I got 4 unique exotics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engram will decrypt into **another exotic item**, not the same item. However, you may get an item for the hunter. There is only a very small chance that it will be the same item that you received from decrypting the exotic engram you already bought.

Answer (score 2):

It is random which item an engram decodes into. This means that two engrams on the same character may be something different. Two engrams on different characters may be different.

Of course being random there is always the possibility that it will turn into the same item. This is just down to the way random works though.